# Get html table data as array using js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need a script where I can get the 2D array of the row and columns of the html table inside div.

The expected output is

```
[
    ["Company", "Contact", "Country"],
    ["Alfreds Futterkiste", "Maria Anders", "Germany"],
    ["Centro comercial Moctezuma", "Francisco Chang", "Mexico"],
    ["Ernst Handel", "Roland Mendel", "Austria"],
    ["Island Trading", "Helen Bennett", "UK"],
    ["Laughing Bacchus Winecellars", "Yoshi Tannamuri", "Canada"],
    ["Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti", "Giovanni Rovelli", "Italy"]
]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="results-table">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
prompt("copy this text",$("#results-table table").text())

</script>
```

I need a script where I can get the 2D array of the row and columns of the html table inside div.

Answer (score 4):

If you obtain a [HTMLTableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement), you can get the rows and then get the cells inside:

```js
const table = document.querySelector("div#results-table > table"), // get the table
  rows = Array.from(table.rows), // get the <tr> elements inside it and convert it to an array
  cells = rows.map(row => Array.from(row.cells).map(cell => cell.textContent)); // gets a 2d list of cells. you could use innerHTML or innerText instead of textContent.
```

Comment: Good catch, thanks. This is proof that I should always test my code.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const trs = document.querySelectorAll('#results-table tr');

const result = [];

for(let tr of trs) {
  let th_td = tr.getElementsByTagName('td');
  if (th_td.length == 0) {
    th_td = tr.getElementsByTagName('th');
  }
  
  let th_td_array = Array.from(th_td); // convert HTMLCollection to an Array
  th_td_array = th_td_array.map(tag => tag.innerText); // get the text of each element
  result.push(th_td_array);
}

console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="results-table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`reducer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), something like

```js
const toValues = [...document.querySelectorAll(`#results-table tr`)]
  .reduce( (acc, row, i) => 
    acc.concat( [ [...row.querySelectorAll(i < 1 ? `th` : `td`) ]
      .map(c => c.textContent) ] ),
  []);
document.querySelector(`pre`).textContent = JSON.stringify(toValues, null, 2);
```

```css
.demo {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<pre></pre>

<div id="results-table" class="demo">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

with this HTML,

```
<div id="results-table">
    <table>
    </table>
</div>
```

use this script to fill the table:-

```
var data = [
    ["Company", "Contact", "Country"],
    ["Alfreds Futterkiste", "Maria Anders", "Germany"],
    ["Centro comercial Moctezuma", "Francisco Chang", "Mexico"],
    ["Ernst Handel", "Roland Mendel", "Austria"],
    ["Island Trading", "Helen Bennett", "UK"],
    ["Laughing Bacchus Winecellars", "Yoshi Tannamuri", "Canada"],
    ["Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti", "Giovanni Rovelli", "Italy"]
];

function fillTable(data) {
    data.map((row, i) => {
        let htmlToAdd = '<tr>'
        row.map(cell => {
            if (i === 0) {
                htmlToAdd += '<th>' + cell + '</th>';
            } else {
                htmlToAdd += '<td>' + cell + '</td>';
            }
        });
        htmlToAdd += '</tr>';
        document.querySelector('#results-table table').innerHTML += htmlToAdd;
    })
}

fillTable(data);
```